# Understanding Objective-C logic

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, nsstring

Hey guys I'm trying to make a basic calculator (polish style) but can't figure out why my code to stop double decimal entry won't work. I found a different way on another thread, but I want to understand why my code won't work. I'm using an nsRange to search the already entered digits in the label for a decimal, then a second conditional to see if the digit to be appended is a decimal   Please help..

```
- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    NSString *digit = [sender currentTitle];  // the number on the button pressed


    NSString *decimalErrorChecker = [[self display] text];  //search line for .
    NSRange range = [decimalErrorChecker rangeOfString:@"."];



    if ((range.location != NSNotFound) && ((digit == @"."))) {  //double if to stop 2nd 
           //SHOW ERROR


    }else  //APPEND DIGIT TO ALREADY ENTERED String.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare NSString using `isEqualToString`, not `==`:

```
if ((range.location != NSNotFound) && [digit isEqualToString: @"."])
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just maintain a flag which indicates whether a decimal has been entered?

```
-(IBAction)digitPressed:(id)sender {
   static BOOL didDecimal = NO;

   // setup yadda

   const BOOL digitIsDecimal = [digit isEqualToString:@"."]; // your use of == here is bad
   if (digitIsDecimal && didDecimal) { error; return; }

   didDecimal |= digitIsDecimal;

   // append yadda
}
```

Of course, this doesn't help if the user deletes the decimal, so perhaps you will need to implement some logic in a UITextViewDelegate...

Comment: thats what i ended up doing, i didn't add a BACK button but rather a clear button, my prob with the clear button is that when i try to set the text label back to "" or "0" or nil it crashes the program, can't figure out why... its such a simple method

    - (IBAction)clearBtn
{

    [[self display] setText:Nil];

}
Why does this crash the program?

Comment: And what is the class of [self display]?

Comment: THIS METHOD WORKS FINE not sure why the other won't
- (IBAction)clearAllBtn 
{
    [[self brain] clearAll];
    [[self display] setText:@"0"];
    [self setUserIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber:NO];
}

Comment: self is the UIVC, display is the UILabel

Comment: Post crash logs, a stack trace, more code, etc. There could be a number of things going on.

Comment: the warning from the compiler is unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a6e1e0'

Comment: That means that whatever class the object 0x6a6e1e0 is does not handle whatever the selector is. The error logs should indicate the recipient class and the selector in question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402621/crash-from-attempting-to-clear-a-calcuator