# Crash from attempting to clear a calcuator

Tags: objective-c, calculator

Hey I'm trying to make a clear button for my polish calculator.. code give me this error when executing the clear button

unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a6e1e0'

there is a button in the interface builder linked to clearBtn

this code is in the CalculatorViewController.m 
display is linked to the UILabel
and..
heres the code

```
- (IBAction)clearBtn
{
if (self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber) {
[[self display] setText:@"0"];
[self setUserIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber:NO];
}    

}

- (IBAction)clearAllBtn //this button works fine.. 
{
[[self brain] clearAll];   // the brain class has a method to set the array to nill
[[self display] setText:@"0"];
[self setUserIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for posting the code. Generally, unrecognized selector errors are not tough, but we need to know which line of code is triggering it, which will help us understand which object is receiving the message, and what the selector is. Can you post a dump of the error messages?

Read about Objective-C selectors [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocSelectors.html).

Generally speaking, Interface Builder is a great tool for... umm, building interfaces. But you do have to be careful about connections and making sure everything is still linked up after making changes to your code or layout.

Comment: finally figured it out!!!   Since clearBtn does not call another class, it needs to have an (id)sender in the method name, in this case I changed the method name to

    -(IBAction)clearBtn: (UIButton *)sender

WHY DOES THIS WORK NOW????

Comment: Because `clearBtn` and `clearBtn:` (with a colon) are two different selectors... see my post.

Comment: We've all been there... just note that the type of formal parameters is actually just a syntax concept, and that there is NO effective difference, either at compile time or at run time between, e.g.  `clearBtn:(id)sender`, `clearBtn:(UIButton *)sender`, or even `clearBtn:(UINavigationController *)sender`. It all gets compiled to Objective-C's `id` type. The only difference is that the compiler will present a warning (not an error) if it detects that you're sending a different type than what your code specifies. And > 1 parameter means colons in the middle... e.g. `tableView:titleForSection:`.

Answer (score 1):

kind of hard to know without seeing the rest of your code, but I'd assuming it's because you don't have a method named `setUserIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber`. Maybe double check the spelling and parameter list?

Comment: he says the second method works fine, which has the same call with the same spelling... I agree it needs more info though (also this is homework from Hegarty's online Stanford class)

Comment: :) @kekekela see comment below